# Definition of cohomology with compact support

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We can define a cohomology on open manifold:

Define a simplicial cochain group
 $$ \Delta^i_c(X;G)$$ consisting of cochains that are **compactly supported** in the sense that they take nonzero values on only finitely many simplices.
  Define the cohomology groups for this complex : 
  $$ H^i_c(X;G)\doteq \operatorname{Ker} \sigma_n/ \operatorname{Im} \sigma_{n-1}$$

Let us give an example : Let us compute these cohomology group when $X=\mathbf{R}$ :
$$ 0\rightarrow
\Delta_c^0(\mathbf{R};G)\rightarrow_{\delta_0=\delta} \Delta_c^1(\mathbf{R};G)\rightarrow 0 $$

Note that $$ \Delta_c^0({\bf R};G)=\{ f :  \mathbf{R}\rightarrow G \mid
f(x)=0 \,\text{ except finitely many points }\, x \} $$ and
 $$ \Delta_c^1(X;G) = \{ f=[a,b] \mid a, b\in \mathbf{R}  \}
$$ Accordingly $$ H_c^0(\mathbf{R};G)=0,$$ since $\delta_0 f=0$ implies
$f$=const.

To compute $H^1(\mathbf{R};G)$ we must consider $\delta$ : $f(0)=a\neq 0\in G$ and $f(x)=0\in G$ for all $x\neq 0\in \mathbf{R}$. Then $\delta f ([0,x]) = f(\partial [0,x]) = 
 f(0)  - f(x) = a $. Since $x$ is arbitarary, $\delta f \in \Delta^1(\mathbf{R};G)$ but $\delta f$ not in $
\Delta^1_c(\mathbf{R};G)$.

What is wrong ? Give me a correction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put a simplicial complex structure on $\mathbb{R}$ in order to define simplicial cohomology on it. Suppose you take the integers for your $0$-skeleton and your 1-simplices to be $[n,n+1]$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The second thing is that the proper definition for an $n$-cochain $f$ with compact support is that there exists a finite subcomplex $K \subset X$ such that such that $f(c) = 0$ for all $n$-chains $c \in \Delta_n(X \setminus K)$.

With this definition, your $\delta f$ is in $\Delta^1_c(\mathbb{R};G)$.

Reference:
http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~jnordstr/wrap.pdf